# Replace regex in a file, in-place, with Common Lisp

Tags: file-io, lisp, common-lisp, idioms, in-place

I am trying to write the Common Lisp version of Python's regex search and replace, with in-place modification of files:

```
import fileinput, re

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1, backup='.bak'):
    line = re.sub(r"foo", "bar", line, re.M)
print (line)
```

This is the Common Lisp code I was able to think up:

```
(require :cl-ppcre)

(defun in-place-subst (file)
  (with-open-file (stream file :direction :io :if-exists :overwrite)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
       while line do
         (write-line (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "foo" line "bar") stream))))
```

It works, sort of. Right now the replacement text will be appended at the end of the file. My immediate problem is that I can't figure out how to *replace* the content.

To better explain, if `file.txt` contains:

```
1 foo
2 bar
3 foobar
```

after calling

```
(in-place-subst "file.txt")
```

I get:

```
1 foo
2 bar
3 foobar
1 bar
2 bar
3 barbar
```

Instead of the right replacement:

```
1 bar
2 bar
3 barbar
```

I tried with all possible `with-open-file` options (from [Successful Lisp](http://www.psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/chapter19.html)), with no success:

```
Keyword      Value                Action if File Exists
----------   ------------------   ---------------------------------------
:IF-EXISTS   NIL                  return NIL
:IF-EXISTS   :ERROR               signal an error
:IF-EXISTS   :NEW-VERSION         next version (or error)
:IF-EXISTS   :RENAME              rename existing, create new
:IF-EXISTS   :SUPERSEDE           replace file upon CLOSE
:IF-EXISTS   :RENAME-AND-DELETE   rename and delete existing, create new
:IF-EXISTS   :OVERWRITE           reuse existing file (position at start)
:IF-EXISTS   :APPEND              reuse existing file (position at end)
```

Could somebody please send me in the right direction, so that the function will render `file.txt` in the correct way?

Also, what would be the Common Lisp **idiomatic** way for doing this, assuming of course `cl-ppcre` is available?

Is there a more succinct way of doing an in-place regex substitution with Common Lisp?

Comment: `FILE-POSITION` reads and sets the file position. You may want to experiment with that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried with `(file-position stream :start)`, trying to reset the stream’s file position, with no much progress. I am sure it is possible to do this with quite a bit more code, (perhaps making a copy in memory, doing the replace and writing back), but I was hoping to find a more succinct, perhaps more idiomatic way.

Comment: Save the file position. read the line. reset the file position to the beginning. write the new line. Note that it does not change the size of lines or expands the file. If your replacement is shorter or longer, then you need to deal with that...

Comment: Thank you, your comment made me think a lot, and helped me understand more of the file-position nuances. It came to me that the easier way would be to write to a temporary file first (like Renzo's answer), especially since piloting the file-position back and forth becomes non-trivial when using regexes whose length cannot be known in advance. Still, your idea is intriguing, and also an excellent exercise. I need to spend more time on it. I feel there could be a more 'lisp-esque' way than the temporary file technique. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I have spent a few hours trying to make the function work, by reading and setting the file position with `FILE-POSITION`. As you were saying, the problem is with substitutions of different length than originals. I almost made it work, but I would need to truncate the stream. It seems such feature is not possible yet, unless one uses Franz: http://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/os-interface.htm#os-truncate-op-bookmarkxx I have also found a proposal: https://www.mail-archive.com/cdr-discuss@common-lisp.net/msg00044.html Do you know of any library that offers that now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python there is no primitive operation that modifies a file “in-place”; instead,
there is a function of an helper class `fileinput`, that gives the illusion of
modifying a file in place by first copying the file to a backup file, and then
reading the backup file and writing the result of processing it to the original one. From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html):

> **Optional in-place filtering:** if the keyword argument `inplace=1` is passed
>   to `fileinput.input()` or to the `FileInput` constructor, the file is moved
>   to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file
>   (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists,
>   it will be replaced silently).
>   This makes it possible to write a filter that rewrites its input file in place.
>   If the backup parameter is given (typically as backup='.'),
>   it specifies the extension for the backup file, and the backup file remains
>   around; by default, the extension is '.bak' and it is deleted when the output
>   file is closed. In-place filtering is disabled when standard input is read.

So, the way of doing this operation in Common Lisp is to mimic the
[Python code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fileinput.py), by first copying the file to a backup file, for instance using this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15813006/2382734) `my-copy-file`, then writing the following code:

```
(defun in-place-subst (file)
  (let ((backup-file (concatenate 'string file ".bak")))
    (my-copy-file file backup-file)
    (with-open-file (in-stream backup-file)
      (with-open-file (out-stream file :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
        (loop for line = (read-line in-stream nil)
           while line do
             (write-line (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "foo" line "bar") out-stream))))))
```